# WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active. Laser Scan Matcher

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, laser-scan-matcher, bagfile, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Kinetic - Ubuntu 16.04

Looking this up, all the forum posts I can find are either about gazebo or don't really have an answer.

Laser Scan Matcher node takes an input and produces an output.  The input isn't empty, I checked with `$ rostopic echo /theinputtopic`.

If I put `<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>`in the node launch file, and I do  `$rostopic echo /outputtopic` , I get:

> WARNING: no messages received and
> simulated time is active. Is /clock
> being published?

If I put `<param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>` in the node launch file, and I do `$rostopic echo /outputtopic` , I get absolutely nothing, just an empty new line.

Putting `--clock` as argument also doesn't seem to have any effect.

What's causing this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288767/warning:-no-messages-received-and-simulated-time-is-active.-laser-scan-matcher/) by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) on 2018-04-28**:
Have you solved this problem yet?  If not, could you post the entire launch file, and maybe a screenshot of an `rqt_graph` of the system running with the bag playback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The input topic was `/tf_static` which only gets sent out a single time, the very first millisecond. The trick is to run everything you need to do (example: `$ rviz` and `$ rosrun somepackage somealgorithm` and *then* run `$ rosbag play bagfile.bag`

This way, `$ rostopic echo /tf_static` isn't empty, and everything functions properly.

Basically, the topic was a bit annoying and had to be run last, otherwise everything else doesn't work.

---

Originally posted by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) with karma: 62 on 2018-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-01-14**:
Can"t understand what your answer has to do with the question